# How can I increase the size of disk?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, virtualbox, disk

I'm using Debian as a VirtualBox guest, but I don’t have enough space. 
How can I increase the size of disk?

[image: VirtualBox storage properties]

[image: VBOX HARDDISK properties]

Answer (score -3):

I will show you how to resize disk in VirtualBox graphically and via command line (for Linux geeks or experienced users).

Both methods are easy and straightforward. The steps are the same for Linux and Windows.

[See HERE](https://itsfoss.com/increase-disk-size-virtualbox/)

Comment: Link-only answer is not a good answer.

Comment: `I will show you` - except, you didn't show anything, you provided a link to someone called Dimitrios who actually does all the hard work

Comment: Can someone explain this step please? "For that, you can download GParted ISO, mount it as an optical drive from the virtual manager settings to find the extra space as “unallocated” space."  Is that mean download the GParted on windows host ? and then install it?

Comment: no, it means exactly what it says @rose - you mount the image in the virtualbox guest optical drive

Comment: No, the GPARTED ISO must be mounted on the VM when it starts, as explained on the DIMITRIOS Link, then with GPARTED launched you will be able to extend with the Disk space with what you added to the VM from VirtuaBox.